# Losing Chest Area Fat

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, training, body-fat

What weight exercises are recommended to lose fat from the chest area, my upper chest is starting to become lean but lower part of my chest is still fatty also all the way around (under armpits) My lower body is reacting well to training but my upper body didn't get the memo.

I saw the **possible dupe** and its wrong, Situations are different. I haven't had any surgery which wont limit the range of workouts i can do. I hit the gym 6/7 days, not 2-3/7

Comment: You can't spot-reduce body fat.

Comment: this question is not a dupe.... -.-

Comment: I would look at the accepted answer in the linked question. If that doesn't help (it should) then I would edit your question to include what you're currently doing that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Even with the edit, the accepted answer is still the same as what would apply to you. No matter how much you hit the gym, or have or not had surgery, you cannot spot reduce fat.

Comment: Voted against reopening. There is _no_ exercise to lose fat from the chest area. _Every_ exercise that burns calories will remove fat all over, _none_ can target the chest explicitly. That's the take-away point, that's what it says in the dupe and whatever differences there are in the question, the answer stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let me set a solid line: If you want to shred down on fat, you cannot target a specific body part like that. In order to reduce the fat off your chest and upper body, you are going to have to take up a program that involves full body fat loss. I would suggest doing cardiovascular exercises for 45 min.- 1 hr. at least 5 days a week. I would personally recommend biking or swimming, but running, tennis, rowing, and even dancing are all significant alternatives as well. I would also highly recommend a change of diet if not being enforced already, with littler amounts of fat and sugar, more protein, and possibly even cutting calories if you are eating too much. Even though bench press may not be as good as cutting fat(but of course still somewhat helpful), it will definitely build a strong chest and I would suggest doing it 2 or 3 times a week.

Comment: That's the thing, I do a lot of compound exercises, yet no change. and yes i do follow a strict diet

Comment: @edrodriguez You need to do cardio.

Comment: i do cardio as well, after weight lifting @robsterach

Comment: @edrodriguez Then keep up this routine. After time you should start seeing total results.